# [EDMX]Mapping table splitting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-4.1

i am working with Entity Framework 4.1 with POCO.
I would like to map table Employees :

```
EmployeeID
LastName
FirstName
ManagerID
IsManager
```

(with ManagerID reflexive association in Employee table)

In

EmployeeBase abstract class contain

```
EmployeeID
LastName
FirstName
```

And Employee class (Inherits EmployeeBase) when IsManager is false contain

```
ManagerID
```

And Manager class (Inherits EmployeeBase) when IsManager is true

My problem is, in context TT i have just `DbSet<EmployeeBase>`. How can I generate `DbSet<Employee>` and `DbSet<Manager>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed explanation to a similar example in this article, the key detail is called "table-per-hierarchy" mapping:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `DbSet` for a derived type. It is how an inheritance mapping works. You always have `DbSet` only for the base type and if you want to run a query only for a sub type you will use `OfType` extension method.

In your case:

```
var query1 = context.Employees;                    // returns all employes and managers
var query2 = context.Employees.OfType<Employee>(); // returns only employees
var query3 = context.Employees.OfType<Manager>();  // returns only managers
```